# Find the limit of the sequence using the "telescopic" formulas

Tags: limits

$${X_n}=\frac{1}{1*5}+\frac{1}{5*9}+\frac{1}{9*13}+ ... +\frac{1}{(4n+1)(4n+5)}$$

Comment: Using partial fraction decomposition woud help.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{1}{(4n+1)(4n+5)}=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{4n+1}-\frac{1}{4n+5})$ use this and try to solve